# Can't display image when list is empty in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am displaying an image in my code when the list is empty. I am using firebase to fetch data and store it in the list since there is no data stored yet so the list is empty initially. But it is not displaying the image on empty condition

Code:

```
         // tab bar view her
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 32, left: 32),
                  child: Medicine(),
                ),

                // second tab bar view widget
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 32, left: 32),
                  child: MedHistory(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      

  Widget Medicine() {
    print("MedicineList ${med_list.length}");
    if(med_list.isEmpty) {
      noMedicine();
    }else {
      ListView.separated(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 11, horizontal: 20),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: false,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return MedicinesList(
                med_list[index].userSdate,
                med_list[index].userReminder,
                med_list[index].userEdate,
                med_list[index].userFreq,
                med_list[index].userDosage,
                med_list[index].userMed,
                med_list[index].key);
          },
          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Container(),
          itemCount: med_list.length);
    }
  }

  Widget noMedicine() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Image.asset(("assets/images/Medicine-amico.png")),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Hurray! You don\'t have any pending medicines to take!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 14,
              color: const Color(0x78000000),
              height: 1.4285714285714286,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

My screen should display this in case the list is empty:

[image]

Kindly help me out in solving the problem, Thank you

Comment: Try adding `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to `Column`

Comment: added that, but still my image is not displayed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using the condition of checking if list is empty or not inside TabView would make it and will display the image as well:

```
Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                  med_list.length == 0
                      ? noMedicine()
                      : ListView.separated(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          primary: false,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return MedicinesList(
                                med_list[index].userSdate,
                                med_list[index].userReminder,
                                med_list[index].userEdate,
                                med_list[index].userFreq,
                                med_list[index].userDosage,
                                med_list[index].userMed,
                                med_list[index].key);
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Container(),
                          itemCount: med_list.length,
                        ),
                
                // second tab bar view widget
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 32, left: 32),
                  child: MedHistory(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `med_list.isEmpty` instead of `med_list.length == 0` in your if check?

Edit: also make the list empty through `List<MedicineList> med_list = [];` or `List<MedicineList> med_list = <MedicineList>[];` instead of `List<MedicineList> med_list = List();`.

Edit 2: The issue was that widgets were made using `Widget name = {}`. A widget has to be a `class` which `extends` either `Stateless` or `Stateful`. It also has to have an `@override build(BuildContext context) {}` fucntion. Please see comments for more details.

Comment: @NabiaSalman is `med_list` nullable? Also, could you please share how you are setting `med_list`? Is it a `FutureBuilder()`, `StreamBuilder()`, or something else?

Comment: i am making a list inisde initState

Comment: incase if i have data, the list will be generated

Comment: Hello @NabiaSalman, if you want to create an empty list, please used `List<MedicineList> med_list = [];` instead of `List<MedicineList> med_list = List();`. If you want to specify the type you can make it `List<MedicineList> med_list = <MedicineList>[];`. Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: i don't think the problem is with the list, since the list is giving 0 in console which mean list has no value in it. 
I used your method of using List as well, none of it worked

Comment: @NabiaSalman After looking at your code again I think that you are incorrectly setting the Widget. Widgets should have an `@override build(BuildContext context)`  method which returns widgets and the class should also extend either `Stateless` or `Stateful` widget. I have to go now but Il will edit your code tomorrow when possible if you are unable to fix the problem yourself.

Comment: i'll try and will let you know if it worked and Thank you

Comment: When I use noMedicine directly from my TabController it displays the picture but when I add the med_list condition it doesn't display anything

Comment: it worked Thank you! I found the solution

Comment: @NabiaSalman Great to hear! May you please suggest an edit to my answer with what specifically worked and i'll accept it or make your own so that the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: i posted an answer to my question since the problem was with the Tab Bar view

Comment: Ok, great. Please mark it as complete as soon as you are able to.